# Redis write dict and retrieve by nested key

Tags: python, json, dictionary, redis

So im working on a project for school but im getting stuck somewhere. I create an object that contains 3 variables; source ip, destination ip, dnsname. I make this in an object, then I wrap it as JSON and write it to Redis with the name "dnsanswer" so the whole line in redis looks like this, when I check if it's written correctly, i get this output:

```
{"srcip": "74.125.136.94", "NA": "www.google.nl", "dstip": "192.168.79.135"}
```

I get this output by using lindex "dnsanswer" -1, which will show me the last added line in Redis.

The thing where I am stuck now is this; I want to be able to just request the "dstip" from Redis. I used rpush to write the object to redis and lindex to see last written line in Redis.

This is the code for the function to write it to redis:

```
def toRedis(pakket):

    r_serv = redis.StrictRedis(host='localhost', port=6379, db=0)

    r_serv.rpush("dnsanswer", pakket) #werkt
    print r_serv.lindex("dnsanswer", -1) #werkt
```

TL;DR How can I receive just a value from a key thats in Redis? (not sure if I formulate it correctly).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The List's member is opaque to Redis, so you can't request just parts of it. What you can do is either deserialize your JSON in your Python code and extract the key that interests you, or use a server-side Lua script (with [`EVAL`](http://redis.io/commands/eval) or [`EVALSHA`](http://redis.io/commands/evalsha)) for that:

```
local member = redis.call('LINDEX', KEYS[1], -1)
local json = cjson.decode(member)
return json[]
```

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. But since you gave me the info that it's not possible, I decided to send it to Redis as a dictionary instead of a object.